# AngularJS HTTP Post shows still error - Working Example needet

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am currently watching an Angular tutorial on HTTPClient post. Unfortunately the tutorial is out of date. So I searched for hours via Google examples/solutions. But even the things I find via Google. Do not work. o,O
I tried this code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-o8b7ri?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

There in Visual Studio I get the error "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"id"' can't be used to index type '{ title: string; }'."
so I changed line 39 to
"let post: any = { id: 'aa' };"
changed.

Now the compiler shows me
"node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts:73:5
73 complete: () => void;"

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it just helps to ask the right question :D

Here is the code. In case someone did not find it on Google either.

HTML-File:

```
<input 
    (keyup.enter)="createPost(title)" #title
    type="text" class="form-control">
<ul class="list-group">
    <li 
    *ngFor="let post of posts"
    class="list-group-item">
    {{ post.title }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

TS-File:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Component({
  selector: 'post',
  templateUrl: './post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post.component.css']
})
export class PostComponent  {
  posts: any;
  private url=`http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { 
    httpClient.get(this.url)
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.posts = response;
      }); 
  }

  createPost(input: HTMLInputElement) {
    let post: any = { title: input.value };
    this.httpClient.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(post))
      .subscribe((response:any) => {
        post['id'] = response.id;
        this.posts.splice(0, 0, post);
        console.log(post['id']);
    });
  }

}
```